# zsh: execute arbitrary aliases inside a function

Tags: zsh

I am trying to write a function like:

```
function myfunc() {
  "$@"
}
```

The actual function does some other stuff, but the key is it is wrapping around an arbitrary input command. Essentially, anytime we type `myfunc <SOMETHING>`, the result should be exactly identical to `<SOMETHING>`, for all possible inputs of `<SOMETHING>`.

This presents a problem with aliases though:

```
$ alias hello="echo hello"
$ myfunc hello
myfunc:1: command not found: hello
```

An alternative I tried is to use `eval`:

```
$ function myfunc2() {
  eval "$@"
}
$ $ myfunc2 hello
hello
$ myfunc2 hello '()'
(eval):1: defining function based on alias `hello'
(eval):1: parse error near `()'
$ hello '()'
hello ()
```

This works in some cases but not others. It seems that `eval` ends up getting a different view of the command since it goes through some processing already (I assume removing the single quotes?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at what actually happens here:

- `hello '()'` tells the shell not to interpret `()` (as starting a function or anything else), but to pass the literal string `()` to `hello`.
- `myfunc2 hello '()'` tells the shell to pass the strings `hello` and `()` to `myfunc2`.
- `eval "$@"` tells the shell "evaluate these strings as if they had been typed on the command line".

Note that the strings you are passing to `myfunc2` are `hello` and `()`, *without quotes*. The quotes are just escape characters to tell the shell not to interpret `()` as anything else than a string. You could also have typed `\(\)` to pass `()` as a literal string (or `\(')'` or `'('\)`; they're all equivalent). These quotes and/or backslashes are not part of the string itself.

So, after the shell expands `"$@"`, `eval "$@"` becomes `eval hello ()` (without the quotes around `()`, since those are not part of the string passed to `myfunc2`), which is then evaluated as if `hello ()` (again, without quotes) had been typed on the command line.

What you need to do is to re-quote the arguments to `myfunc2`:

```sh
% alias hello="echo hello"
% myfunc2 () {
  eval "${(q)@}"
}
% myfunc2 hello '()'
hello ()
% myfunc2 hello \(\) \(')' '('\)
hello () () ()
%
```

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea about all of these parameter expansion options. Found a full list here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion. Thanks!